# Qt Signals and Slots object disconnect?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I am wondering if i need to disconnect singals and slots if i destroy the signal emitting object. Here is an example:

```cpp
QAudioOutput * audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(format,mainWindow);
connect(audioOutput,SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)),this,SLOT(stateChanged(QAudio::State)));

delete audioOutput;

audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(format,mainWindow);
connect(audioOutput,SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)),this,SLOT(stateChanged(QAudio::State)));
```

Will this automatically disconnect the signal from the old audioOutput, or will it lead to mem leaks or some other undefined behavior ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Although `QObject`s safely clean up connections when they are destroyed I would recommend against deleting a `QObject` that has already had its parent set as you have above since this will short circuit the automatic mechanisms already in place for `QObject`s. It is also generally safer to use `deleteLater()` instead of deleting a `QObject` directly.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The signals are automatically disconnected when you call the QObject destructor.
Have a look at the Qt documentation: [QObject Destructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to manually `disconnect()` signals and slots, the `QObject` destruction cleans them up automatically.