# Proper way to disconnect signals from two QObjects not being destroyed/deleted

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

What is the proper way to disconnect two QObject's from each other such that no more signals emitted from one object trigger slots in the other object?  Neither object is going to be destroyed so `disconnect()` [will not be called in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264750/qt-signals-and-slots-object-disconnect) `QObject::~QObject()`.  I see two versions of the `disconnect()` method in the documentation, and neither one takes a pointer to two objects.

It is important that no more signals are received into the receiving objects slots after disconnect.  A few triggers while the buffer clears unprocessed signals is OK, but the signals must stop within a very short time.

There seems to be some confusion about the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#disconnect):

> [To] Disconnect a specific receiver:
>
> ```
> disconnect(myObject, 0, myReceiver, 0);
> ```

Once this has been called, all connections from `myObject`'s signals to `myReceiver`'s slots will be disconnected.

Comment: Thanks!  For future readers you can also use `myobject->disconnect( myReceiver );` to be more elegant.

Comment: You should use nullptr instead of 0 to avoid warnings.