# How to edit a buttons connection in Qt

Tags: qt

EDIT: I do not want to call the object destructor as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264750/qt-signals-and-slots-object-disconnect).

I have connected a button to a slot. This slot starts a process.

```
ui->btnActivate->setText("Start");
connect(ui->btnActivate, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(startProcess()));
```

After the process finishes, I do

```
ui->btnActivate->setText("Close");
connect(ui->btnActivate, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(close()));
```

But now the button starts the process and then run close. How can I disconnect the first connection before altering the buttons behaviour? I would like to avoid calling the Destructor

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt Signals and Slots object disconnect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264750/qt-signals-and-slots-object-disconnect)

Comment: You can disconnect the signal from the slot : `disconnect(ui->btnActivate, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(startProcess()));`

Comment: @Nejat Thank you, this worked. I did not want to use the destructor so this was perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use 1 of the 5 signatures of [QObject::disconnect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnect) to simply remove a connection between 2 objects without destroying any of them.