# Can signal handlers memory leak in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, events, pyqt, signals-slots

**Short question:**

Can signal handlers memory leak.

**Long question:**

In C#, if I attach a handler to an event

```
left_object.left_event += right_object.right_handler
```

Then I need to remove the handler when I get rid of `right_object` or the garbage collector will never dispose of it (since `left_object.left_event` retains a pointer to `right_object`)

Is the same also true of ***PyQt*** signals and slots.

```
left_object.left_signal.connect( right_object.right_handler )
```

I see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264750/qt-signals-and-slots-object-disconnect) question that Qt automatically delinks signals and slots, when the destructor of either `left_object` or `right_object` is called, but in Python I cannot explicitly call the destructor, and `right_handler` is a plain-old-function.

Do I need to remove the handler to prevent `right_object`s memory-leaking, or does PyQt use some sort of weak-referencing?

While one of the answers touches on this, [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941743/lifetime-of-object-in-lambda-connected-to-pyqtsignal) asks about how PyQt handles objects inside lambda expressions, not how PyQt handles signals.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47941743/984421.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have a memory leak with this design. You need to disconnect the signals and slots if those connections contain references which are keeping objects alive.

Whether or not this actually happens depends on what exactly `right_handler` is. If `right_handler` is a closure with a reference to `self` then you have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> but in Python I cannot explicitly call the destructor,

You can call destructor in python. Check [del](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) and [__del__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__del__#object.__del__)

> Do I need to remove the handler to prevent right_objects memory-leaking,

No, you don't need to do that. python will handle that. Run below code check your self.

In this code signal of `startButton1` and `stopButton1` are connected to methods of class object of `Hello` and this object(`hello1`) is attribute of Widget class. So `hello1` will live until life object of `Widget` OR we delete it in method `Widget.onDelete` with `Delete` button. Once you click `Delete` button, destructor of `hello1` is called and it will goes out of scope. Now signal of `startButton1` and `stopButton1` don't work as before.

Now in second row there are buttons `startButton2` and `stopButton2`, whose signal are connected with object of `hello2`. But as soon as construct of `Widget` is over `hello2` life time is finish. So there is not slot connected for signal of those buttons after `Widget` construct is over.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QPushButton,QWidget,QHBoxLayout,QVBoxLayout

class Hello():
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")

    def onStart(self):
        print("onStart");

    def onStop(self):
        print("onStop");

    def __del__(self):
        print("del")

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent);
        vLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(vLayout)
        buttons1 = QWidget()
        hLayout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        buttons1.setLayout(hLayout1)
        vLayout.addWidget(buttons1)
        startButton1 = QPushButton("Start");
        stopButton1 = QPushButton("Stop");
        deleteButton1 = QPushButton("Delete");
        self.hello1 = Hello();
        startButton1.clicked.connect(self.hello1.onStart)
        stopButton1.clicked.connect(self.hello1.onStop)
        deleteButton1.clicked.connect(self.onDelete)
        hLayout1.addWidget(startButton1);
        hLayout1.addWidget(stopButton1);
        hLayout1.addWidget(deleteButton1);

        buttons2 = QWidget()
        hLayout2 = QHBoxLayout()
        buttons2.setLayout(hLayout2)
        vLayout.addWidget(buttons2)
        startButton2 = QPushButton("Start");
        stopButton2 = QPushButton("Stop");
        deleteButton = QPushButton("Delete");
        hello2 = Hello();
        startButton2.clicked.connect(hello2.onStart)
        stopButton2.clicked.connect(hello2.onStop)
        hLayout2.addWidget(startButton2);
        hLayout2.addWidget(stopButton2);


    def onDelete(self):
        if hasattr(self,"hello1"):
            del self.hello1

app = QApplication([])
w = Widget();
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Hope this will clear you doubt.

Comment: This is not correct. `del` does not delete an object. It just removes one reference to it. For example, if you have `foo.a = []`, `foo.b = foo.a` then `del foo.b` will still leave the object live as it is still referenced by `foo.a`. If signals keep objects alive, as the original question asks, then `del` will not help solve this problem.